# Rails + Jasmine-Ajax: what is the correct way to test code triggered by `ajax:success` (jquery-ujs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jasmine

I am trying to test a certain internal library that has some JS behavior triggered on the `ajax:success` event.

The library creates a link that looks like this:

```
<%= link_to 'click here', '/some_path', class: 'special-link', remote: true %>
```

And in the JS part of the library there is event binding code, **which is the part I want to black-box test through its effect on the DOM**:

```
$(document).on 'ajax:success', '.special-link', (e, data, status, xhr) ->
  # Code that has some effect on the DOM as a function of the server response
```

The library works as expected in the browser. However, when I try to test the library in Jasmine by calling `$('.special-link').click()`, the desirable effect on the DOM cannot be observed.

The issue, it seems, is that the `ajax:success` event does not get triggered:

```
describe 'my library', ->
  beforeEach ->
    MagicLamp.load('fixture') # Fixture library that injects the link above to the DOM
    jasmine.Ajax.install()
    jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('/some_path').andReturn({
      responseText: 'response that is supposed to trigger some effect on the DOM'})

  afterEach ->
    jasmine.Ajax.uninstall()

  # Works. The fixtures are loading properly
  it '[sanity] loads fixtures correctly', ->
    expect($('.special-link').length).toEqual(1)

  # Works. The jquery-ujs correctly triggers an ajax request on click
  it '[sanity] triggers the ajax call', ->
    $('.special-link').click() 
    expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().url).toContain('/some_path')

  # Works. Code that tests a click event-triggering seems to be supported by Jasmine
  it '[sanity] knows how to handle click events', ->
    spy = jasmine.createSpy('my spy')
    $('.special-link').on 'click', spy
    $('.special-link').click()
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()

  # Does not work. Same code from above on the desired `ajax:success` event does not work
  it 'knows how to handle ajax:success events', ->
    spy = jasmine.createSpy('my spy')
    $('.special-link').on 'ajax:success', spy
    $('.special-link').click()
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

What is the right way to test the effect on the DOM of code that runs in `ajax:success` events?

Comment: I've answered kind of similar question recently, does that help in any way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943055/how-to-test-json-inside-function-using-jasmine/36947887#36947887

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply spying on the `ajax` function? For that, you need to use `spyOn` and force it to call the `success` event handler. That will let you test what you expect to happen when it's called.

```
it 'knows how to handle ajax:success events', ->
  spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake( (e) ->
    e.success({});
  )

  $('.special-link').click()

  # expect some method to be called or something to be changed in the DOM
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we would handle this sort of thing on my team.

```
it 'knows how to handle ajax:success events', ->
  spyOn($.fn, 'on');
  $('.special-link').click()
  expect($.fn.on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('ajax:success', 
                                       '.special-link'
                                       some_func);
```

This pattern extends well to testing other 'on' events, too. Say we have some jQuery like this:

```
$document.on('myCustomEvent', '.some_selector', somecode.custom_func);
$document.on('ajax:error', '.some_selector', somecode.failure_func);
```

Then we can test it using this pattern:

```
beforeEach ->
  spyOn($.fn, 'on');
  somecode.init();
```

**Testing an Ajax failure**

```
it('indicates failure after ajax error', ->
  expect($.fn.on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('ajax:error',
                                       '.some_selector',
                                       somecode.failure_func);
```

**Testing Ajax was called from custom event**

```
it('indicates ajax call from custom event', ->
  expect($.fn.on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('myCustomEvent',
                                       '.some_selector',
                                       somecode.custom_func);
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging, I found a solution.

When I posted my question, I made 3 critical mistakes.

### Mistake #1: `jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest` path is not relative

The Ajax call was not stubbed correctly, since the path should not be the relative `/some_path` but rather the absolute `http://localhost:3000/some_path` when testing from the browser.

In other words, instead of:

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('/some_path')
```

I should have used the regexp version:

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest(/.*\/some_path/)
```

### Mistake #2: `jasmine.Ajax.andReturn` must include cotentType

Instead of:

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest(/.*\/some_path/).andReturn({
  responseText: 'response that is supposed to trigger some effect on the DOM'})
```

I should have done:

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest(/.*\/some_path/).andReturn({
      contentType: 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
      responseText: 'response that is supposed to trigger some effect on the DOM'})
```

Without it, the `ajax:error` is triggered rather than `ajax:success`, with a `parseerror`.

### Mistake #3: The `ajax:success` handler is called async-ly

These lines of code:

```
spy = jasmine.createSpy('my spy')
$('.special-link').on 'ajax:success', spy
$('.special-link').click()
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

don't work, since the `ajax:success` handler that calls `spy()` is called asynchronously after `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()` is reached. You can read more about this in [Jasmine documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support).

### Putting it all together

This is the code that works, focusing only on the last `it` statement which was the main intent behind the original question:

```
describe 'my library', ->
  beforeEach ->
    MagicLamp.load('fixture') # Fixture library that injects the link above to the DOM
    jasmine.Ajax.install()
    jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest(/.*\/some_path/).andReturn({
      contentType: 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
      responseText: 'response that is supposed to trigger some effect on the DOM'})

  afterEach ->
    jasmine.Ajax.uninstall()

  # Restructuring the original `it` statement to allow async handling
  describe 'ajax:success event handling', ->
    spy = jasmine.createSpy('spy')

    # Ensures no `it` statement runs before `done()` is called
    beforeEach (done) ->
      $('.special-link').on 'ajax:success', ->
        spy()
        done()

      $('.special-link').click()    

    it 'knows how to handle ajax:success events', ->
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Hope this helps others.