# How to test json inside function using jasmine?

Tags: json, jasmine

This is the code that I want to test:

```
function loadNotification(searchOption, searchKey) {
   var url = '@URLs.API.Notifications.Past' + '?searchOption=' + searchOption + '&searchValue=' + searchKey;
   $.getJSON(url)
      .done(function (nData) {
        //some code here
      })
      .fail(function (jqXHR, status, error) {
        showError('There was an error while fetching the records. Please try after some time. (' + jqXHR.status + ':' + jqXHR.statusText + ')');
      });
}
```

Using *jasmine*, how do I test if the *json* file fails or not? I was thinking of using *.done* and *.fail* but I'm not sure if it's possible. I don't know much about *json*. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

when testing AJAX requests (and similar, fetching json file etc.), it's always a good idea to check that your code can handle both done and fail. You should also mock  the data that you test, don't rely much on actual endpoints in your application or files that it tries to download. You want the test to run as fast as possible.

Using Jasmine you can do a few things:

**using a spy:**

spyOn is a function that can stub a given function and track what kind of arguments were passed to it, can see what other function called it and even return a specific value when the code that it's spied on executes.

You could use a spy to see that the $.get request will happen, and then you can say return a specific value, and continue testing the program.

**using Jasmine Ajax plugin**

This is what I like to use in my tests. Jasmine has a very nice plugin [ajax.js](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html). It simplifies testing any ajax functionality. What I like to do is to mock the actual request, so when your code would tries to get a file/response, the code will ignore the actual call and mock it, returning fake data that you can specify.

Before I start, I also like to have my ajax method in a separate function, it will just return a promise. It's much easier to read/test/maintain, so for example you could rewrite it like:

```
this.loadNotificationCall = function(searchOption, searchKey) {
    var url = '@URLs.API.Notifications.Past' + '?searchOption=' + searchOption + '&searchValue=' + searchKey;
    return $.getJSON(url)
} 

this.loadNotification() {
    return this.loadNotificationCall()
        .done(function (nData) {
            //some code here
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, status, error) {
            showError('There was an error while fetching the records. Please try after some time. (' + jqXHR.status + ':' + jqXHR.statusText + ')');
        });
}
```

If you load your test app with dummy data, I guess you expect the ajax request file to have a specific path.

You're looking at most basic, default version of what you can output from

```
'@URLs.API.Notifications.Past' + '?searchOption=' + searchOption + '&searchValue=' + searchKey;
```

Let's say it's something like

```
//'someapi?searchOption=1&searchValue=abc'
```

That url needs to exactly match to what will your application would attempt to contact. Check your debug/fiddler and see what is that just in case. If it's not matched (including the data it's trying to send) the mock will fail, and test will timeout. The error usually looks like `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

Once you get that right, you can mock that url in the following example:

```
describe('when user gets the data', function() {

var sut = null;
var testCall = null;
var dummyData = {
    name: 'Jon Snow'
};
beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.Ajax.install();
    jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest("someapi?searchOption=1&searchValue=abc").andReturn({
            responseText: JSON.stringify(dummyData)
    });

    sut = new yourApplication();
    testCall = sut.loadNotification();
});

afterEach(function() {
    jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
});

// actual tests here

});
```

I'm also pretty sure that you can use wildcards in those mock urls, so this should also be valid: `jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest("someapi?(.*)").andReturn(//`

So what happens now is, if you test something that will call your method with $.get, the request won't happen to your server, but instead it will be mocked and our dummy data will be returned. In this example it's a simple object with `name: 'Jon Snow'`

Now, you want to have a test that looks something like this:

```
it('should populate name', function(done) {
    testCall
        .done(function() {
            expect(sut.name).toEqual('Jon Snow');
            done();
        });
});
```

You pass done argument to the test, so that it won't finish until the call is finished. If you debug it in your browser, you will see that code in your file will go inside done method and continue working as it was a real request. The data in `done(nData)` will become our dummy object with `name: Jon Snow`.

If you wanted to test a failing code, you can add some additional settings to ajax plugin:

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest("someapi?searchOption=1&searchValue=abc").andReturn({
    status: 500,
    responseText: "{}"
});
```

I hope I didn't bore you with this much, I know that there are simplier methods (such as just doing $.spy on 'ajax' and seeing the most recent call etc. but I like my method, has worked very well and I can test multiple calls, chained calls, and many more cool scenarios.

Comment: thank you @kasperoo for the detailed reply. i will go ahead and try those with my test. i appreciate it! hopefully, i can get it to work.

Comment: if i cannot change the function that has the ajax call (it was programmed by another developer), i can go ahead and mock it using the code you presented above right?

Comment: Correct, given that promise is returned

Comment: im kind of confused with this:
       sut = new yourApplication();

im not sure what to put on sut. the function im testing resides in a cshtml file. am i missing something here? im sorry if it seems a stupid question but im really new to all this.

Comment: SUT means `System Under Test`. It's an instance of a class that you test. It's whatever that starts your application, your main object. There are no stupid questions! Looks like your first problem is the fact that JS is part of HTML page - you really need to separate it, otherwise it's really hard to test anything in that setup. You should to bind all your functions (methods) together in an object which you could instantiate (using `new`), and play with. That's how it should be done at least.

Comment: You could hack it together, not needing the `sut`, just testing individual functions - I wouldn't advise, but I guess that's possible. Check out http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-your-javascript-with-jasmine--net-21229

Comment: yeah that;s what i thought too. i am aware that sut means system under test so i know im not that stupid. lol. but im not sure how will the developers react if i tell them to separate the js file from html since we are already close to our first release. ill look into the hack that you mentioned. thanks kasperoo. this might not be the last time im asking questions though. appreciate the help! cheers!

Comment: checked the link and i didnt find anything about ajax calls. ill do more research on how to "hack" it for now. ill open up the conversation about separating the html and js files to the developers when i get the chance. thanks for all your help kasperoo!

Comment: If my developers insisted on having inline JS, I'd leave my job, simple as that ;p